# Best Practice for flex consuming Java web services

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, actionscript

We are planning to use flex and Java Web Services, what is the best practice to consume web service from flex is it better to directly call the web service from Action scripts or to use remoting where java client will call the web services and later flex using remoting will the java client?

Comment: No matter what you decide to use as a point of integration - the Flex client or using Java middle-ware such as SpringDS, the Flex side would still be relatively the same. A more valuable question for me would be the discussion of the best practices for consuming services on the Flex-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flex provides connection to web services why would want to you use a java client. Anyway, the best way to connect java and flex, IMHO, would be to use blazeds, either you're using webservices or another connection method. In case you are using spring framework, you should take a look at [spring flex integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex)

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice with cross domain constraints and the only solution is to use a middleware such as BlazeDS, SpringDS or GraniteDS as a proxy between the Flex client and the actual service.